# Addcomment method errors

Tags: excel, vba

I'm facing a problem with the .AddComment function

```
    Worksheets("Config").Range("I2:ZZ2").offset(index, 0).AddComment Worksheets("Library").Range("B2:ZZ2").offset(offset, 0).Value
```

What am I doing wrong? Im looping so a "With" statement is not possible here.

Comment: You have to apply it to each cell in turn, not the entire range in one go.

Comment: You also have to make sure the cell you're trying to add a comment to doesn't already contain a comment.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I do clear every cell before add comments to it.

Comment: @Rory I don't understand this. How should I write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through each column as well:

```
for i = 9 to 702
    Worksheets("Config").Cells(2 + index, i).AddComment Worksheets("Library").Cells(2 + index, i).Value
next i
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I get errors when no value available in the "Library" worksheet...

Comment: @MattijnStegeman you won't get an error just because the cell in the Library sheet is empty.

Comment: All is working now. Thank you so much for this answer!